# Use gcloud or python APIs for building an application in google cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Am building an application to manage images. Wondering if I should use the gcloud command line tool to use gcp functionality or should i use the python REST based SDK to do that? Reason is gcloud seems simpler to use (but understand that parsing etc. might be a pain). Interested in hearing thoughts from folks who have gone down this route and made a choice.

Thanks
Girish

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a more detailed explanation on what you want to achieve? App Engine offers [Images API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/) to manipulate image data.